# How to combine the Module Dependencies with the Dependencies of its parent Module with Mill

Tags: scala, mill

I want to combine the Module Dependencies with the ones from the parent Module.

I have the following in my `build.sc`:

```
  trait ExampleModule extends ModuleWithTests {
    override def moduleDeps = Seq(camunda, cli)
  }    
  object twitter extends ExampleModule {
    override def moduleDeps = super.moduleDeps ++ Seq(twitterApi)
  }
```

This gives me:

```
build.sc:222: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[build.this.ModuleWithTests]
 required: Seq[build.this.ModuleWithTests{def moduleDeps: Seq[build.this.ModuleWithTests]}]
    override def moduleDeps = super.moduleDeps ++ Seq(twitterApi)
                                               ^
build.sc:222: `T.command` definitions must have 1 parameter list
    override def moduleDeps = super.moduleDeps ++ Seq(twitterApi)
                 ^
Compilation Failed
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or do I have to list the module dependencies in each child module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is almost right, but because you omitted the explicit return type of `ExampleModule.moduleDeps` it seems the compiler inferred a more specific type of `Seq[ModuleWithTests]` in this case. Looks like all your modules `camunda` and `cli` also implement this trait. Whereas `twitterApi` seems to not implement it.

To fix the compile error, you might try to add the explicit return type `Seq[JavaModule]` to `ExampleModule.moduleDeps`.